# Delete index in a DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using Python and I have a DataFrama as the following:

[image]

I need to delete all the index (columns/rows) in order to get only the name of the columns. How can I do this? please. By the way, I'm using google colab to run the code.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code used ?

Comment: no Images, please share the data as a code. refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @abokey sure, this is the code that I'm using:

from google.colab import auth
import gspread
from google.auth import default
#autenticating to google
auth.authenticate_user()
creds, _ = default()
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

import pandas as pd
#defining my worksheet
worksheet = gc.open('my_sheet').sheet1
#get_all_values gives a list of rows
rows = worksheet.get_all_values()
#Convert to a DataFrame 
b2chat = pd.DataFrame(rows)

Comment: Thanks @Juan. Can you show more of your google sheet so we can see the columns names (A, B, C..) and rows numbers (1, 2, ..) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wanting the first row as headers?

```
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0])
```